# Getting access to class's variables inside another class's def

Tags: python, string, class, instance-variables

I'm trying override a **str** method in Person() class:

'''class Person(object):

```
def __init__(self, Nose = None, Neck = None, RShoulder = None, RElbow = None, RWrist = None, LShoulder = None, LElbow = None, LWrist = None, MidHip = None, RHip = None, RKnee = None, RAnkle = None, LHip = None, LKnee = None, LAnkle = None, REye = None, LEye = None, REar = None, LEar = None, LBigToe = None, LSmallToe = None, LHeel = None, RBigToe = None, RSmallToe = None, RHeel = None):
    self.Nose = Nose
    self.Neck = Neck
    self.RShoulder = RShoulder
    self.RElbow = RElbow
    self.RWrist = RWrist
    self.LShoulder = LShoulder
    self.LElbow = LElbow
    self.LWrist = LWrist
    self.MidHip = MidHip
    self.RHip = RHip
    self.RKnee = RKnee
    self.RAnkle = RAnkle
    self.LHip = LHip
    self.LKnee = LKnee
    self.LAnkle = LAnkle
    self.REye = REye
    self.LEye = LEye
    self.REar = REar
    self.LEar = LEar
    self.LBigToe = LBigToe
    self.LSmallToe = LSmallToe
    self.LHeel = LHeel
    self.RBigToe = RBigToe
    self.RSmallToe = RSmallToe
    self.RHeel = RHeel
def __str__(self):
    return 'Nose = %s\nNeck = \n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s'%(self.Nose,self.Neck,self.RShoulder,self.RElbow,self.RWrist,self.LShoulder,self.LElbow,self.LWrist,self.MidHip,self.RHip,self.RKnee,self.RAnkle,self.LHip,self.LKnee,self.LAnkle,self.REye,self.LEye,self.REar,self.LEar,self.LBigToe,self.LSmallToe,self.LHeel,self.RBigToe,self.RSmallToe,self.RHeel)'''
```

And I want to find more elegant way to return a string which will look like that:

Nose = something

Neck = something
...
...
...

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**:  elegant way to return a string which will look like ...

You can use the built-in `vars` function to get the `__dict__` of the class variable and format it using `.format(...` and `.join(...`.

---

**Reference**:

- [`vars([object])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars)

  > Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.
- [`.format(value[, format_spec])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

  > Convert a value to a “formatted” representation, as controlled by a standard formatting syntax that is used by most built-in types: [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).
- [`<str>.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

  > Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

---

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.Nose = kwargs.get('Nose', None)
        self.Neck = kwargs.get('Neck', None)
        self.RShoulder = kwargs.get('RShoulder', None)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(('{} = {}'
                          .format(k, v) for k, v in vars(self).items()))


p = Person(Nose=1, Neck=1)    
print(p)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Nose = 1
> Neck = 1
> RShoulder = None
> ```

---

***Tested with Python: 3.6***

Comment: When I run it I get an error: AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @NickSahno: See LIVE DEMO at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ScalyRecklessPackages). You have probably a typo in this part `...vars(self).items()...`